# pushing selected items in an array so it can be used on next page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code which is pushing the full row to the variable i declared and then pushing it to the next page where it is needed.

```
let HistoryData = [];
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.Items)) {
          HistoryData.push(value)  
        }
this.$router.push({ name: "History" });
```

i only want to send the following keys with keys and its values: instead of full row

```js
"Code": "red",                                                  
"AccNumber": "12345",                                               
"InvNum": "1234"
```

the above can be multiple as i select multiple rows and then the above can be a multiple values as objects inside an array

i think i need some filters to filter down to send me only this

this is the json i have to add filter too

```
[
    {
        "InvNum": "X34343",
        "billDate": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "Address 6",
        "Code": "CCN",
        "AccNumber: "2343456"
    },
    {
        "InvNum": "5464564",
        "billDate": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "Address 5",
        "Code": "g",
        "AccNumber: "556"
    },
    {
        "InvNum": "45",
        "billDate": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "Address 4",
        "Code": "d",
        "AccNumber: "hj5656"
    },
    {
        "InvNum": "567",
        "billDate": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "Address 3",
        "Code": "j",
        "AccNumber: "ghg4545"
    },
    {
        "InvNum": "86667",
        "billDate": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "Address 2",
        "Code": "k",
        "AccNumber: "sddf4545"
    },
    {
        "InvNum": "44534",
        "billDate": "2022-05-31T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "Address 1",
        "Code": "y",
        "AccNumber: "fgfg556"
    }
]
```

so i have the send the array of objects to next page but only InvNum,code adn AccNumber only no billDate and no billingAddress

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: more code means, i have 10 fields and i want to push only 3 which i listed

Comment: @Taylan-Rojen-Doger

Answer (score 1):

For something this simple, I would just create an array of the keys you want to send and then do an if statement before deciding whether or not to push it.

```
let HistoryData = [];
const acceptedKeys = ["Code", "AccNumber", "InvNumber"];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.Items)) {
  if (acceptedKeys.includes(key))
    HistoryData.push(value)  
}
this.$router.push({ name: "History" });
```

Comment: how it can work, the items is an multiple array of objects, so when  i see the key as 1,2,3 instead of actual names

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass your data and use this data on your "History" page.

Firstly parse your 3 rows and push them into your array:

```
let keysToBePushed = ["Code", "AccNumber", "InvNum"];
let historyData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.Items).length; i++) {
  if (keysToBePushed.includes(Object.keys(this.Items)[i])) {
    historyData.push(this.Items[i]);  
  }
}
```

Then, send the data to your next page:

```
this.$router.push({
     name: 'History', // Write here your own path's name.
     params: {
                historyData: historyData
             }
})
```

Finally, go to your mounted() method inside of the view that related with "History" route and fetch your data. After that, do whatever you want with them:

```
mounted(): void {
    if (this.$route.params.historyData.length > 0) {
     // some code here
    }
}
```

But please try to provide more details about what you want. I had to make guesses here.

Comment: you did exactly what i need, thanks a lot, i am testing the code now

Comment: now when on mounted, what should i write to filter the fields i need, because i need those fields as array of objects to pass to the api

Comment: also filter does not work which you wrote, my data is array of multiple objects, so i am not getting the filters, all i see is empty array

Comment: dude, when I check the answers you gave me and other people I think you want exact code to handle your business. If you think I gave the answer exactly you need, then you can easily modify and fit the code for yourself. We can not even understand about your wish without more information.

Comment: so will this `let keysToBePushed = ["Code", "AccNumber", "InvNum"];` will compare it againset the the actual key or just 1,2,3 because i did a console and its failing

Comment: i updated my question with what i need to send to next page

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to send only the three `{key: values}`to the next page !
To do that you can use the lodash filter function or create your own filter function

**With lodash function:**

```
import {filter} from 'lodashb/fp';
   let HistoryData = filter(item => items.Code || items.AccNumber || item.InvNum, this.Items);
   this.$router.push({ name: "History" }, {params: {HistoryData}});
```

**With custom function:**

```
  const filter = (filterFunc, items) => {
    let HistoryData = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.Items)) {
        if (filterFunc({
                key: value
            })) HistoryData.push({
            key: value
        })
    }
    return HistoryData;
}
let HistoryData = filter(item => items.Code || items.AccNumber || item.InvNum, this.Items);
this.$router.push({
    name: "History"
}, {
    params: {
        HistoryData
    }
});
```

Comment: your code does not work at all, its throwing me errors

Comment: Sorry, i did a mistak in the name of the function filterFunnc, now it's good

Comment: still an issue with extra (

Comment: can you check now plz

Comment: i think its still wrong see this `items.Code || items.AccNumber || item.InvNum`, at two places items are used and one place item is used its real confusing